# Pass conditions to subqueries - rails activerecords

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a QuestionCategory model who hasMany Question.

When I do this query `@quizzs = QuestionsCategory.find(:all)` everything is ok. It's querying all the catégories and associated questions:

```
QuestionsCategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `questions_categories`.* FROM `questions_categories` 
  Question Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`questions_category_id` = 1
  Question Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`questions_category_id` = 2
  Question Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`questions_category_id` = 3
```

But, I'd like to pass a condition to the questions subqueries. Something like
`@quizzs = QuestionsCategory.find(:all, :questions => [ :conditions => {MY CONDITIONS} ])`

And then get subqueries looking like this:

SELECT questions.* FROM questions WHERE questions.questions_category_id = 2 `AND MY CONDITIONS`

Possible?
Cheers mates

Comment: are you using rails 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

To get result for your `SQL` ( `SELECT questions.* FROM questions WHERE questions.questions_category_id = 2 AND MY CONDITIONS`) you can do as follows:

```
  QuetionsCategory.find(2).questions.all(:conditions => [Your conditions])
```

Comment: That's the result I want, BUT I'd like to automatically apply this condition to the subqueries by calling the single line `QuestionsCategory.find(:all)`. It will always be the same condition for each subqueries. Otherwise I must do a loop...

Comment: Then you need to use `join` : `QuetionsCategory.joins(:questions).where( Your conditions)`

Answer (score 0):

How about a scope?

Question category controller:

```
def your_action_name
  @quizzs = QuestionsCategory.all.collect{|qc| qc.questions.published == true}
```

Question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, where(:published => true)
end
```

This way you can chain all the scopes (conditions) you'd like to apply to a `Question`

Answer (score 0):

You Need Default scope In your model.

puts this In you QuestionCategory model.

```
default_scope joins(:questions).where(conditions)
```

Then

QuestionCategory.all Should give you  expected result.